# React-datepicker with a Formik form

Tags: reactjs, forms, date, formik, react-datepicker

I'm trying to use react-datepicker in a Formik form.

I have:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


class Fuate extends React.Component {
    state = {
        dueDate: new Date()

    }

<Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                    title: Yup.string().required("A title is required "),
                })}

                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}

                render={({ 
                    errors, 
                    status, 
                    touched, 
                    setFieldValue,
                    setFieldTouched, 
                    handleChange, 
                    handleBlur,
                    handleSubmit, 
                    isSubmitting, 
                    dirty, 
                    values 
                }) => {

                return (
                    <div>
            ...

<DatePicker
                                            name={'dueDate'}
                                            value={values['dueDate']}
                                            onChange={e => setFieldValue('dueDate', e)}
                                        />
                                        <DatePicker
                                        style={{ width: 180 }}
                                        date={values.dueDate}
                                        mode="date"
                                        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                        minDate={Date.now.toString()}
                                        maxDate="2050-06-01"
                                        confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                                        cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                                        showIcon={false}
                                        customStyles={{
                                            dateInput: {
                                            marginLeft: 0,
                                            borderColor: "#fff"
                                            }
                                        }}
                                        onDateChange={date => setFieldValue("dueDate", date)}
                                        onTouch={setFieldTouched}
                                        />
```

For both of these options, the form renders, I can select a date on the calendar but it does not appear in the box and the state value is not updated with the selection.

There are no errors in the console, but the warning says:

> Starting with v2.0.0-beta.1 date-fns doesn't accept strings as
>   arguments. Please use `parseISO` to parse strings. See:
>   toDate @ index.js:45

I tried making the initial state:

```
dueDate: new Date().toISOString(),
```

but it makes no difference.

I've seen lots of posts about setting this up with Antd's date picker, but can't find instructions for how to do it with react-datepicker.

Comment: Never mind everyone. Ive given up trying to figure this out. I found react-formik-ui an it works just fine

Comment: Still answering because this question is valid and may be useful for someone with same query in future.

Answer (score 74):

Update to [Dani Vijay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56320889/199364).
This uses [`useField`](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField) and [`useFormikContext`](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext) from Formik v2, to simplify usage of the component.

DatePicker.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useField, useFormikContext } from "formik";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export const DatePickerField = ({ ...props }) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field] = useField(props);
  return (
    <DatePicker
      {...field}
      {...props}
      selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}
      onChange={val => {
        setFieldValue(field.name, val);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Usage (see Dani's answer for the complete form declaration):

```
...
<DatePickerField name="date" />
...
```

[Code at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-react-datepicker-demo-he69x)

Comment: This is the best answer now (as of end of 2019)

Comment: There is also a direct `setValue` helper.
`const [field,, { setValue }] = useField(props);`
and then `onChange={val => setValue(val)}`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve on your demo, as soon as I click in the field I get `RangeError
Use 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY' for formatting years; see: https://git.io/fxCyr`

Comment: Looks like a problem with the demo. I don't get that problem if I copy'n'paste your DatePicker component locally. I get other errors when selecting a date, but I think that's unrelated to your code. Thanks.

Comment: @Wodin - thanks - fixed. (I had to update `react-datepicker` version to one that matches the latest version of `react`. The message was from a default date format string inside react-datepicker.)

Comment: Do you guys know how to answer my question that arises from this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312273/typescript-error-and-the-spread-operator-arising-from-props

Comment: This solution also works with Material UI Pickers if anyone else is wondering

Comment: How about react-native, can you use `useField` with react-native?

Comment: @eugene - while I have not tested this with React Native, it should work (assuming you are using Formik 2 or higher).

Comment: There's a problem with this: Formik doesn't put `is-invalid` on this control when it fails validation.

Comment: @geneb. - hmm. Its been awhile since I wrote this. I don't remember whether I tested to see if it was working back then. So I'm not sure if that is due to some recent change, or there is some problem with this technique. Were you able to find a solution? If you were, go ahead and edit this answer. OR if some different technique works, please link to that. OR create a new question, and put a link to that question here. OR if you solved it yourself, would be great if you create a question, and add your own answer to it. Either way, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks no worries, I figured out my issue. I was referring to libraries like React-Bootstrap or Material-UI setting the `is-invalid` or `error` class on the React-Datapicker, similar to other controls, to enable common styling and error messages. To support that, we just need to pass to this wrapper the `isInvalid` or `error` prop, and **manually set className** , e.g. `className={"form-control " + props.isInvalid ? "is-invalid" : ""}`. In other words, there's a bit more manual work to make the datepicker fit those React component libraries in terms of error styling.

Comment: I found an issue with Formik/Yup and this solution. Any non-Required validation requires re-touching the datepicker to be propagated, while Required validation is triggered right away. It could be a Yup issue. I created a thread on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662804/react-datepicker-with-formik-and-yup-date-value-not-validated-on-first-blur-ot

Comment: One thing confused me initially - using this, you don't add `onChange` and `value`  props, you don't need them, it works w/o them.

Comment: I am having error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setFieldValue')` when try to destructure  `useFormikContext()` hook

Answer (score 30):

[react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) can used with [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) by utilising [setFieldValue](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void),

```
const DatePickerField = ({ name, value, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <DatePicker
            selected={(value && new Date(value)) || null}
            onChange={val => {
                onChange(name, val);
            }}
        />
    );
};

const App = () => (
    <Formik
        initialValues={{ date: "" }}
        ...
    >
        {props => {
            const {
                values,
                handleSubmit,
                setFieldValue
                ...
            } = props;
            return (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <DatePickerField
                        name="date"
                        value={values.date}
                        onChange={setFieldValue}
                    />
                    ...
```

CodeSandbox demo [**here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-reactdatepicker-demo-yi45m)

Comment: I don't know why I had to do that : 
 onChange={(val) => setFieldValue('date', val)}

Comment: @DamienRomito - my guess: If you use `DatePicker` directly, that is what you need to do. This answer moves that logic into the `DatePickerField` component, which is a wrapper around `DatePicker`. There, it can use the `name` parameter, so don't have to hard-code the name `'date'`.

Comment: @DaniVijay - using Formik v2's `useFormikContext` and `useField`, the usage of DatePickerField can be simplified, so don't need to explicitly pass in `value` and `onChange` on each call. [Updated demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-react-datepicker-demo-1zz6e). Usage: `<DatePicker name="date" />`. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650742/199364).

Answer (score 4):

Update to [Dani Vijay and ToolmakerSteve's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650742/16150505):

Use `setValue` directly instead of `setFieldValue`. Based on [@asologor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650742/16150505).

```
import React from "react";
import { useField } from "formik";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export const DatePickerField = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [field, , { setValue }] = useField(props);
  return (
    <DatePicker
      {...field}
      {...props}
      selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}
      onChange={(val) => {
        setValue(val);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Note: This method lets you to use Formik with `react-datepicker`, but it also works for other UI Libraries like **Material-UI** and **Ant Design** too.

Comment: This answer was useful for working with NextJs, being used as 
```<DatePickerField minDate={new Date()} dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" id="date_run" placeholderText="Enter date yyyy/mm/dd"    {...formik.getFieldProps('date_run')}/>```. However loading the previously saved data `2022-02-23T22:00:00.000Z` does not automatically switch to the dateFormat (yyyy/MM/dd), but stays in the raw date/time format.

Answer (score 3):

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {    
     date:""
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  }); 

 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                  <KeyboardDatePicker
                    disableToolbar
                    variant="inline"
                    TextFieldComponent={(params) => {
                      return <TextField className={classes.TextField} 
                       {...params} variant="outlined" />;
                    }}
                    format="dd MMM yyyy"
                    margin="normal"
                    name="installDate"
                    value={formik.values.date}
                    onChange={(newDate) => {

                       //use this here
                      formik.setFieldValue("date", newDate);


                    }}
                    KeyboardButtonProps={{
                      "aria-label": "change date",
                    }}
                  />
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I see from your code is DatePicker is not inside of Formik. In React.js we always create reusable components so keep the code clean and easy to test. To be able to use DatePicker in your code, create a separate file, write your code for Datepicker and render it as a component of the Field. here is how you should implement.

```
//First let's start with structure of Formik.
import PortDate from "./form/PortDate";
//define your components in a different directory. I named it form
const CreateForm = props => (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{"your initial values"}}
        validate={your validation function here}
        onSubmit={values => {
          return props.onSubmit(values);
        }}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting }) => (
          <Form>     
            <Field name="startDate" component={DatePicker} label="Start Date" />

            <Field
              name="endDate"
              component={DatePicker}
              label="End Date"
              canBeDisabled={true}
            />

          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
```

now in a different component let's implement our Datepicker logic.
    //Use reactstrap instead of bootstrap when you want to add style

```
import { FormGroup, Label } from "reactstrap";
class DatePicker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        dueDate: new Date(),
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    setFieldValueAndTouched(date, touched) {
      const { setFieldValue, setFieldTouched } = this.props.form;
      const { name } = this.props.field;
      setFieldValue(name, date, true); //field,value,shouldValidate
      setFieldTouched(name, touched, true); //field,touched,shouldValidate
    }
    handleChange(date) {

      this.setState(() => ({ dateValue: date }));
      this.setFieldValueAndTouched(date, true);    }

    render() {
      const { dueDate } = this.state;
      const {
        label,
        field,
        form: { touched, errors },
      } = this.props;
      // field and form props are passed to this component automatically because we render this inside component of the Field. 
      return (
        <FormGroup>
          <Label>{label}</Label>
          <div className="input-group">

              <DatePicker

                selected={dueDate}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                peekNextMonth
                showMonthDropdown
                showYearDropdown
                maxDate={new Date()}
                dropdownMode="select"
              />

          </div>
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }
  }

  export default DatePicker;
```

Comment: The question is about using [an existing DatePicker class, defined in an imported module](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/src/index.jsx). There isn't any code in the question to move to a different file; its simply a form containing two `<DatePicker>` elements. Sorry, I think your answer is not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

How to make this to work for the date range picker:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
const [field] = useField({ name: name, value: startDate });
const [field2] = useField({ name: name2, value: endDate });

<GroupContainer>
 <DatePicker
    {...field}
    onFocus={() => setFocusStart(true)}
    onCalendarClose={() => setFocusStart(false)}
    selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}
    onChange={(val) => {
                    setStartDate(val);
                    setFieldValue(field.name, val);
                }}
    dateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" 
    selectsStart                            
    minDate={new Date()}                                
            />
</GroupContainer>

<GroupContainer>
  <DatePicker
    {...field2}
    onFocus={() => setFocusEnd(true)}
    onCalendarClose={() => setFocusEnd(false)}          
    selected={(field2.value && new Date(field2.value)) || null}
    onChange={(val) => {
            setEndDate(val);
            setFieldValue(field2.name, val);
                }}
    dateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"         
    selectsEnd
    minDate={new Date()}        
            />
</GroupContainer>
```

Then:

```
<ReactDatePicker name="arrivalDate" name2="departureDate" />
```