# Formik with react-naitve, using useField?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I don't use formik's `Field` with react-native

because doc says `<Field /> will default to an HTML <input /> element`

I'd like to use `useField` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650742/433570)
and wonder `useField` is usable with react-native?

```
import React from "react";
import { useField, useFormikContext } from "formik";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export const DatePickerField = ({ ...props }) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field] = useField(props);
  return (
    <DatePicker
      {...field}
      {...props}
      selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}
      onChange={val => {
        setFieldValue(field.name, val);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but if it's only "useField is usable with react-native?" then your answer is yes