# Maximum update depth exceeded. in `react-DatePicker` with `Formik`

Tags: reactjs, date, react-hooks, react-datepicker

I'm using `react-datePicker` package in `Formik` and
this error pops up initially rendering page

```
react-dom.development.js:23803 Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

***[referred this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312372/react-datepicker-with-a-formik-form)***

```
<DatePicker
      {...field}
      {...props}
      selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}  
      onChange={val => {
        setFieldValue(field.name, val);
      }}
    />
```

in my case the problem is initially `field.value` is `NaN-NaN-NaN` later its is fetched and set to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

How to validate `NaN` in  `selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}`

Answer (score 1):

Try to set initial field value with `new Date()`, helps for me