# React-Datepicker with Formik and Yup: Date value not validated on first blur, other than .required()

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, formik, yup

I'm using React-Datepicker inside a Formik form validated with Yup. To integrate React-Datepicker inside Formik I used the [wrapper solution in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650742/1005607).

When a value is initially entered, `.required()` gets checked, but any other validation does **not** get checked. So I'm not getting my `StartDate later than today` validation right away. These other validations do get triggered if I re-enter the control a second time and exit it. So the only initial validation error that happens immediately is `.required()`, but for any other errors I need to re-touch the control. Are there any solutions to this?

**EDIT:** I noticed that Formik's `.touched` does not get set on the 1st DatePicker input. It only gets set on subsequent touches/inputs.

**Yup**

```
startDate: yup.date().nullable().required('Start Date is required')
                                .min(new Date(), 'Start Date must be later than today'),
```

**DatePicker Wrapper** -[see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650742/1005607) - credit to *ToolmakerStever*

I tried adding `onCalendarClose` to force re-validation per this DatePicker [issue report](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/2028), and it indeed may be happening, but this could also be a Yup Schema issue -- I'm not sure.

```
const { setFieldValue, validateField, values, handleBlur } = useFormikContext();

   return (
        <DatePicker
            {...field} 
            {...props} 
            showMonthDropdown
            showYearDropdown            
            selected={(field.value && new Date(field.value)) || null}
            onChange={val => {
                setFieldValue(field.name, val);
            }}
            onCalendarClose={val => {
                // Force-validate onCalendarClose to avoid any potential DatePicker Blur issues
                // Didn't help
                validateField(props.name);
            }} 
            onBlur={e => {
                // Call Formik's handleBlur
                // Didn't help
                handleBlur(e);
            }}           
          
        />

    )
```

Comment: can you create a sandbox and share . It will be easier to debug and help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a fix. Something wasn't marking the DatePicker as `touched` the first time. DatePicker exposes an event called `onChangeRaw` where I force-touched the control. Now all errors are triggered right away without re-touching.

```
        onChangeRaw={e => {
            setFieldTouched(field.name, true, true);
        }}
```

This goes inside the DatePicker Wrapper for Formik, [as shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58650742/1005607).

React-Datepicker has a bug with Blur for some reason, [documented here](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/2028). Their Blur recommendations include calling `onCalendarClose` or `onChangeRaw`. But only `onChangeRaw` worked reliably for me.

Comment: In my case, I misspelled the name of the field in Yup object (it was different than in initialValues object.)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a wrapper with Field works fine . The validations are getting triggered without any issues. Here is the sandbox.

[Formik DatePicker Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-thunder-y4ub5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes, but you only tested the `errors` attribute. The problem was the `touched` attribute. On first input, the `touched` was not getting set. You had to refocus the control and only then would get the correct `touched` behavior. My Formik error depends on **both** `errors` and `touched` to display an error.

Comment: Formik by default will trigger a validation if the field is touched. In the sandbox which i have shared . You can just click on the input field and click outside you can see the touched attribute getting populated .

Comment: No, in your sandbox if I click 'May 5, 2021", the `touched` on this control is **not** set **the first time**  after making a selection and closing the calendar. That should already make it touched, I shouldn't need to additionally click outside again. But if you re-focus the control then it will get set. That's the DatePicker Blur bug. I show my error message in a custom way depending on **both** `error` and `touched`, so that's how I ran into this bug. `touched` should be set immediately on making a selection.

Comment: That makes sense . Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for your sandbox, also. It's helpful to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those using react-hook-form with yup, trigger onBlur inside onChange

```
<Controller
 name='dateOfBirth'
 control={control}
 render={({ field: { name, value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
  <DatePicker
      selected={value}
      preventOpenOnFocus={true}
      maxDate={new Date()}
      dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
      placeholderText='YYYY-MM-DD'
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onChange={(date: Date) => {
        onChange(date);
        onBlur();
      }}
      customInput={<DatePickerInput/>}
    />
```